Can you auto-continue on continuable error with clisp (or sbcl)?
This seems like an obvious question but my Googling suggests the answer is no, which I find hard to believe. I'm just starting out using examples from textbooks, and get the following. I have to type "continue" 4 times before I can get to my repl (in clisp).
$ clisp  -i auxfns.lsp  -i 4_general_problem_solver.lsp


...


** - Continuable Error
DEFUN/DEFMACRO(DEBUG): #<PACKAGE COMMON-LISP> is locked
If you continue (by typing 'continue'): Ignore the lock and proceed

Notes

I'm using this example: https://github.com/norvig/paip-lisp/blob/main/lisp/gps1.lisp


Shouldn't you be more interested in fixing the cause of the error?

(auxfns.lsp redefines a number of standard functions, which is normally not allowed, but includes ways for a number of cl implementations to give it a pass; gnu clisp is not one of them.)

Try -on-error exit for clisp.

Establish a handler around problematic code:
(handler-bind ((error 'continue)) (cerror "Continue" "Dummy error")).
Preferably change the ERROR to the error type you want to continue on.

You can wrap IGNORE-ERRORS around the problematic code. http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_ignore.htm

PAIP should use own namespace for those functions it overwrites from CL-USER - then, I think this error wouldn't occur.
In the repository, there are not (in-package :paip) at the beginning of the files.
quickloading :paip package results in firing up the debugger. After continuing, there is another error of an undefined function. I wonder, why such a central book's repo is not really taken care of.

Thanks for all the input, I will get back to this when I next have the brainpower. Like Shawn said, the book probably aims to deal with the most vanilla Lisp distribution (and is quite an old book).

Locking/Unlocking packages in CLISP: https://clisp.sourceforge.io/impnotes/pack-lock.html

Yes, you can.  For instance this macro:
(defmacro continuing (&body forms)
  `(handler-bind
       ((error #'continue))
     ,@forms))

will invoke the continue restart for errors which have one, or where there is a continue restart not associated with any condition.
You almost never want to do this.  In particular, in this case, the system is signalling errors because the program is trying to make modifications to symbols in the CL package.  The CL package contains symbols which name all the basic functions and variables of Common Lisp, so this is almost never something you want to do, and certainly it is only something you want to do when you know exactly the consequences of doing that.
I have no idea why the PAIP code thinks it is reasonable to do this.

The original PAIP code does not use packages. Everything is in the CL-USER package, then. The file auxfns.lisp for example defines a function called symbol. Common Lisp has a symbol named symbol in the COMMON-LISP package. At the time when the book was written, ANSI CL wasn't yet published -> implementations were probably less strict with defining functions on existing CL symbols, even when in CL they were not functions.

@RainerJoswig: yeah, what confuses me is that someone – Norvig I assume – went ahead and added all the 'disable package checks' stuff to auxfns.lisp without somehow thinking 'these implementations are trying to tell me not to do this, perhaps I should ... learn about packages?'.  That's like 'fixing' warnings by redirecting error output to /dev/null.

I would think that he knows about packages. He is not dumb. But he certainly wanted to avoid the added complexity of packages and then the book was already printed. I would think that the idea was to make the code work without changes to the relevant book code. Actual maintenance of his Lisp code ended decades ago...
